# get the data or content of the selected column

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to retrieve the content from a specific column, below is what I tried

```
//get the department
$department = department::where('user_dep', '=', 1)->select('dep_id')->get();
//but seems the department retrieved an array, which I dont want, I want only the content
$notification = notification::where('department', '=', $department)->get();
```

but sadly not working. Seems the `$department` retrieved an array like the title of the column and its value I think.

I tried to replace the `$department` unto a specific integer(1) and it retrieved the record (it works) but if I use `$department` it returns me an empty result. Any ideas?

```
$notification = notification::where('department', '=', 1)->get();
```

the vard_dump result of the $department

```
object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)[206]
protected 'items' => 
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    object(App\department)[210]
      protected 'table' => string 'department' (length=10)
      protected 'connection' => null
      protected 'primaryKey' => string 'id' (length=2)
      protected 'perPage' => int 15
      public 'incrementing' => boolean true
      public 'timestamps' => boolean true
      protected 'attributes' => 
        array (size=1)
          ...
      protected 'original' => 
        array (size=1)
          ...
      protected 'relations' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'hidden' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'visible' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'appends' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'fillable' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'guarded' => 
        array (size=1)
          ...
      protected 'dates' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'casts' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'touches' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'observables' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'with' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
      protected 'morphClass' => null
      public 'exists' => boolean true
```

Comment: what is the output of `$department`?

Comment: its null when displaying it through var dump and in json response "department: [{dep_id: 1}]" but if i tried to return it to the javascript e.g. alert, it gives me "object object"

Comment: @RonakPatelL: please see my updated post.

Comment: Have you tried `$department = department::where('user_dep', '=', 1)->lists('dep_id')->get()`?

Comment: @user2094178: yes and I got this error "Call to a member function get() on a non-object"

Comment: You can also do `$department = department::where('user_dep', '=', 1)->first()->dep_id` if you are looking for one row.

Comment: i got this error "Trying to get property of non-object"

Comment: This would mean `dep_id` is null.

Answer (score 1):

Problem was being caused by the usage of the wrong closure method in Eloquent. Using `->get()` will fetch all rows that match the given criteria (even if you're only looking for a single row) and return it as a collection of objects. Using `->first()` will (logically) find the first matching row and return it as a single object. There would be two ways to structure this problem:

Option 1:

```
$department = department::where('user_dep', '=', 1)->select('dep_id')->get();
$notification = notification::where('department', '=', $department[0]->dep_id)->get();
// var_dump($department); would equate to an array of `department` items;
```

Return the whole collection, but only look for the 1st result's `dep_id`.

Option 2:

```
$department = department::where('user_dep', '=', 1)->select('dep_id')->first();
$notification = notification::where('department', '=', $department->dep_id)->get();
// var_dump($department); would equate to a single `department` item;
```

Find the first row and return the noticifcation based on its `dep_id`. Either method works, but Option 2 would be the more straight-forward choice.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
$department = department::where('user_dep', '=', 1)->select('dep_id')->get();
$notification = notification::where('department', '=', (int) $department)->get();
```

Comment: i tried yours and I get this "Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection could not be converted to int"

Comment: That means you are not getting correct out put from your query. Can you please `var_dump($department)`?

Comment: `$department` is an object of `department`s, so calling `where('department', '=', (int)$department)` would return the above message.

Comment: @TimLewis: Yeah. that's what I figured. SO needs to get data from that object and then try to convert it in `int`.

Comment: Well there is data, but it's a collection of data. If he used `department::where('user_dep', '=', 1)->select('dep_id')->first()` instead of `->get()` it might work like so: `$notification = notification::where('department', '=', $department->dep_id)->get()`